# How to zoom out embedded google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, embed

In my website I'm using an embedded google map using the following code ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5xe9h5o/)):

```
<iframe
    width="300"
    height="170"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.3735618,4.8943677&hl=es;z=3&amp;output=embed">
    </iframe>
```

The map shows fine, but I want the map to show a large area (i.e. zoom out a bit). I tried varying the value of `z` in the url, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Does anybody know how I can show a large area with this embedded google map? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the url you use in src is wrong,in order to separate parameters you must use `&`

it's work with this url :
`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.3735618,4.8943677&hl=es&z=15&output=embed`

you can play with the zoom parameter here (1-20 values) :
http://jsfiddle.net/e5w4enb5/